# C++ while loop not running

Tags: c++, while-loop

my while loop wont run on the conditions I set it.

The purpose of the program is to determine the amount of years it will take a deposited amount to mature using the deposit amount, interest rate and target amount.

The program just stops after the target amount has been entered, unless I change the while statement from <= to >= in which case it runs the loop but returns the number of years set at round 100's or 1000 etc...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //declare the variables
    double rate,
           balance = 0;
    int deposit,
        target,
        years = 0;
    cout << "****Lets make you some money!****" << endl << endl;
    //input from the user
    cout << "What is your deposit amount?: " << endl;
    cin >> deposit;
    cout << "What is your interest rate?: " << endl;
    cin >> rate;
    cout << "What is you target savings amount?: " << endl;
    cin >> target;
    rate = rate / 100;
    while (balance <= target); //when i change this to balance >= target the 'while' runs but just returns years divisible by 100
    {
        // calculation
        balance += deposit * pow((1 + rate), years);
        //balance = balance*(1 + rate) + deposit;   // alternate calculation
        //years++; 
        //users savings target
        cout << "You will reach your target savings amount in: " << balance << " years." << endl << endl << " That's not that long now is it?" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using a debugger? Set a breakpoint and examine the state of your program. What is the actual value of `balance` and `target`? Where are they getting their values from?

Comment: It might be problamatic, since you're comparibg an int to a double.

Comment: @445646 And what's problematic about that, in this case?  (There is a possible issue because he's using `double` for money values.  But his real numeric issue is the way he calculates the balance,  At least, I'd love to have a savings account where the balance was calculated like that.)

Comment: @JamesKanze what do you mean?

Comment: @molebox Well, it's not clear exactly what sort of financial instrument you're trying to simulate, but if you invest say $1000 at 5% compounded annually, you'll get $1276.28.  Run your simulation for five year, and you'll get more than $5000.  There's clearly an error in your formula.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is an unfortunate suffix:

```
while (balance <= target);
//                       ^
```

That is equivalently:

```
while (balance <= target) {
    ;
}
{
    // calculation, which always runs exactly once
    // regardless of what balance/target are
}
```

Just drop the semicolon.

Comment: Oh, well thats embarrassing! Sorry for the bloody awful question then and thank you for taking the time the answer it!